# In American football, can a player intentionally fake an injury to stop the clock?

Tags: rules, american-football, injuries

Wondering if this is against the rules or if it’s a loophole for teams to stop the clock and use it like a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could pretend to get injured to get a timeout. The standard play clock length makes it mostly pointless though. But because of the possibility, the NFL has a rule stating that players that cause injury timeouts must leave the field for at least one play and under two minutes to go in the half, an injury timeout also causes the team to lose a timeout.